# Laravel проверка прав пользователя

Tags: php, laravel, аутентификация

Есть маршрут, в который передаётся имя пользователя и slug задачи

```
Route::get('/task/{username}/{slug}', [TaskController::class, 'task'])->name('task');
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы никакой другой пользователь не смог просмотреть эту задачу. Т.е мне нужно что бы только пользователь, который указан в url, смог просматривать задачу

Получается сделать вот таким образом, но мне кажется это костыль и у Laravel есть специальный инструмент для этого

```
public function task($username, $slug)
    {
        $to_user = User::whereName($username)->first();
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user->name == $to_user->name) {
            return view('profile.task');
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В таких случая лучше использовать `middleware`

1. Создаем `middleware`

   class TaskMiddleware
   {

   ```
        public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
        {
            $username = $request->route()->parameter('username');

            if($username !== \Auth::getName()) {
                abort(403);
            }

            return $next($request);
        }

    }
   ```
2. Регистрируем его в роуте

   `Route::middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\TaskMiddleware::class)->get('/task/{username}/{slug}', [TaskController::class, 'task'])->name('task');`
3. В самом контроллере реализовываем логику обработки отображения самой задачи

Почему стоит выбрать такой вариант:
В случае если вам нужно будет реализовать функционал для разрешений пользователей. К примеру вам завтра поставят задачу "Вот сделай так само но нужно еще чтобы мой аккаунт видел ВСЕ задачи" - вы просто меняете логику мидлвера, а не ищите в контроллерах где именно вы еще используете подобную логику.